# Unique visitor query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find out the number of unique visitirs for each day and I have the data base like this :

```
UID   clicks date
6046    9   2013-03-06
6449    7   2013-03-06
6450    41  2013-03-06
664     2   2013-03-07
2432    36  2013-03-07
3246    11  2013-03-07
6031    52  2013-03-07
```

Now what I need to find is the number of unique visitor count for each day. I am finding this along with the sum of clicks for that day. So the query is like this  :

```
SELECT date,SUM(clicks) as new_clicks,COUNT(DISTINCT uID) as unique_clicks 
FROM uc_user 
WHERE date <='2013-03-15' GROUP BY date;
```

But here I am getting wrong results. The count is different from the counts that I calculated for same interval using

```
SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT uID ) AS unique_clicks
FROM uc_user
WHERE date <= '2013-03-15'
GROUP BY date
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What is the difference between these queries and which one is correct for displaying the number of unique visitors ?

Actually My actual query in PHP is like this :

```
 SELECT date,SUM(clicks) as new_clicks,COUNT(uID) as unique_clicks 
 FROM currencyclick_user 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
 GROUP BY date
```

and

```
 SELECT SUM(clicks) as total_new_clicks,
        COUNT(DISTINCT uID) as total_new_uniqueclicks  
 FROM currencyclick_user 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

but for the same ranges, it is showing different values. I mean the sum query is displaying a wrong total than the value I get by adding the counts in the first query.

Comment: Your count of user ids looks the same in both queries.  It should work fine.  Is the query you have posted the actual query that is causing the problem, or is it a simplified one?

Comment: it should be like 3 for 2013-03-06 and 4 for 2013-03-07 as all the ids are unique. It should not add if one UID repeates. That is if one ID that is 664 has entry in 2013-03-06 , it shouldn't consider in any of the following days counts

Comment: i found the same. see here, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cfb2/3 (*unless you update the record*)

Comment: can you show the expected output for the above table ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have updated your question, the two queries on lowermost of your question are very different because in the first one, you have grouped the records by date and while the second you didn't. The first query will return different records for each day while the second one will only return one record because you have not specy on the query on which column do you want to group.

If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

- [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)
- [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  SUM(new_clicks) totalClicks,
        SUM(unique_clicks) totalUnique
FROM
    (
        SELECT  date,
                SUM(clicks) as new_clicks,
                COUNT(uID) as unique_clicks 
        FROM    currencyclick_user 
        WHERE   date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
        GROUP   BY date
    ) subQ
```

Comment: actually what I need is the total sum. I mean the total number of unique visitirs in the given rage, how can I do this ?

Comment: ok, see my updated answer. you need to put it inside a subquery

Answer (score 0):

To find total number of unique visits in a range try this query

```
SELECT  SUM(clicks) totalClicks,
    count(distinct UID) totalUnique
FROM
(
    SELECT UID,dtm,clicks
    FROM    currencyclick_user 
    WHERE   dtm BETWEEN '2013-03-06' AND '2013-03-07' 
) as allclicks
```

Comment: But I think in the sub query, it select the visitors from given period.So it may not give the count of unique visitors for the whole period. I mean this will not check, if UID is repeated before the given range.

Comment: Yes inner query doesn't,but the outer query gives unique memebers for the period.